# I have this code but whenever I input a word such as cow it stops working

Tags: python

Whenever I run this code it doesn't allow inputs such as `cow`. I have included the term `float` as I would like number and word input. I can enter numbers but not words. Has anyone got an idea where I am going wrong?

my output should look like :

How many strings do you want to enter:3

Enter string 1: 2

Enter string 2:-4

Enter string 3:cow

No of positive numbers entered is: 1

```py
def main():
    global countervalue
    countervalue=0
    string=int(input("How many strings do you want to enter? "))

    for num in range(1,string+1):
        value=float(input("Enter string %a: "%num))
        IsPos(value)
    print("No of positive whole numbers entered is:",countervalue)

def IsPos(val):
    global countervalue
    if val.is_integer() and val>=0:
        countervalue+=1
    return countervalue;

main()
```

Comment: `float(input("Enter string %a: "%num))` .. you're trying to convert the string to a floating-point number. If you enter "cow", this will fail.

Comment: Assuming you wrote this yourself, why would you *expect* it to accept `cow`?

Comment: So, don't enter strings like `"cow"`, enter numbers like `42`.

Comment: @Aziz how can i fix the issue

Comment: Why are you calling `float` in the first place? Do you want strings, as the prompt suggests, or do you want numbers, as `IsPos` suggests?

Comment: @quamrana It needs to include words

Comment: @chepner to allow number and word input

Comment: @Barbra Please clarify what you're trying to do in this code. Edit your question and add more details.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: So try: `value=input("Enter string %a: "%num)`. Does it work now?

Comment: @quamrana when I remove float I get an error message which is this here AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_integer'

Comment: use `try` and `expect` to keep the program running

Comment: @Kendle but I need the words to be entered into the above input because I have a part two to the question were I have to work out the number of other strings entered

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to test whether the input value is a number or not by converting to `float` and catching the resulting exception:

```py
def main():
    global countervalue
    countervalue = 0
    string = int(input("How many strings do you want to enter? "))

    for num in range(1, string+1):
        value = input("Enter string %a: " % num)
        IsPos(value)
    print("No of positive whole numbers entered is:", countervalue)

def IsPos(val):
    global countervalue
    try:
        fval = float(val)
        if fval.is_integer() and fval >= 0:
            countervalue += 1
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return countervalue

main()
```

Output as requested